# ld: library not found for -lASIHTTPRequest : XCode13.4

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've opened a old project, I can not able to run the code because of the following error

***ld: library not found for -lASIHTTPRequest***

I tried
Re Install all the pods

I Opened .WorkSpace

I Tried,
Delete Library Search Paths

I Tried, $(inhereted) in Library paths

[image]

Comment: Looks like this got uninstalled? https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens when the pod gets updated, and the pod owner gets rid of some internal dependencies (in your case ASIHTTPRequest), but the Cocoapods fails to remove all the references to the removed dependency completely for some unknown to me reason.

In such cases you can do that manually.
Open the build settings of your target, and search for "Other Linker Flags".
Double click on it, locate `ASIHTTPRequest`, and remove both: that line and the line before it: "-framework".

[image]